# Suma de filas y columnas

Tags: c

Tengo una matriz de 10x10 y necesito sumar las filas y las columnas como se muestra en la imagen. Ya tengo hecha la matriz con el recorrido que me piden y sume los elementos de cada fila y cada columna (aunque no se si sirva) pero no logro sacar la parte de la suma entre filas y columnas.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) { 
    int i, j;
    int x = -1;
    int mat[10][10];
    int suma;
    int vert[10];
    int horiz[10];

    printf("\n");
    printf("Recorrido de la matriz\n");
    printf("\n");

    // bucle de matriz
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x = x + 1;
            mat[i][j] = x;
        }

    // impresion de la matriz 
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            printf("%3d\t", mat[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    // suma de cada fila
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        suma = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            suma += mat[i][j];
            vert[i] = suma;
        }
    }

    // suma de cada columna
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        suma = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            suma += mat[i][j];
            horiz[j] = suma;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("fila %d\n", vert[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        printf("columna %d\n", horiz[j]);
    printf("\n\n");
```

Comment: La suma de filas y columnas que tienes actualmente no te sirve, porque en ambas está toda la fila y toda la columna. Debes hacer un recorrido diferente para tomar los elementos que abarca cada _suma especial_, según se ve en el diagrama. La idea de estos ejercicios es ayudarte a desarrollar la lógica de la programación, por lo que una respuesta que te de justo esa parte, sin que lo hayas intentado al menos un poco más te haría más daño que bien.

Comment: tip: Una manera de conseguir el recorrido como te lo están pidiendo es realizar ciclos anidados. Date cuenta que para cada iteración, debes recorrer solamente parte de la fila y parte de la columna (a partir de que se intersectan).

Comment: y si agregas 10-i ----> for(j=0;j<10-i;j++)

Answer (score 0):

Este algoritmo sigue un patrón muy fácil de replicar:

[image]

- Por cada fila, suma los elementos hasta la columna "*FILAS - fila*".
- Suma los elementos de la columna "*COLUMNAS - fila*" desde la fila "*fila* + 1".

```
    for (int fila = 0; fila != TAMANYO; ++fila)
    {
        int limite = TAMANYO - fila;
        int suma = 0;

        for (int indice = 0; indice != limite; ++indice)
        {
            suma += matriz[fila][indice];
        }

        for (int indice = fila + 1; indice != TAMANYO; ++indice)
        {
            suma += matriz[indice][limite - 1];
        }

        printf("La suma %d es: %d\n", fila, suma);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para estos problemas es bueno hacer un recorrido preliminar y ver como se comportan los valores en nuevas iteraciones:

1era iteracion (n=0):
horizontalmente [0,0] a [0,9] y luego verticalmente [1,9] a [9,9]

2da iteracion (n=1):
horizontalmente [1,0] a [1,8] y luego verticalmente [2,8] a [9,8]

y con ello te das cuenta de que cambia cada iteracion, y que se queda fijo, relacionandolo a la variable de iteracion (i), por lo que quedaria expresado en algo asi:

n-esima iteracion:
[n,0] a [n,9-n] y luego [n+1, 9-n] a [9, 9-n]

Asi las iteraciones pueden quedar:

```
int sumas[10];
for (n=0; n<10; n++){
   sumas[n] = 0;
   for (j=0; j<9-n; j++){
      sumas[n] += mat[n,j]
   }
   for (i=n+1; i<10; i++){
      sumas[n] += mat[i,9-n]
   }
}
```

Asi en cada sumas[n] se guarda la suma de cada fila/columna.

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de que ya han respondido a la pregunta satisfactoriamente, te propongo una forma alternativa de solucionar el problema.

El recorrido de una fila, o de una columna, ya sea completa o no, implica un bucle, que normalmente vendrá anidado dentro de otro si lo que queremos es recorrer varias filas.

Pero como se puede observar en la imagen, se pretende hacer un recorrido de media fila, para terminar con otro recorrido de la columna correspondiente, por tanto, y como se ha hecho en otras soluciones, habrá dos bucles, uno para recorrer media fila, y otro para recorrer media columna. Como queremos hacer muchos recorridos análogos, esos dos bucles estarán anidados en un bucle más grande.

Si te fijas bien, verás que el punto en el que el recorrido cambia de horizontal a vertical (lo que se traducirá en cambiar del primer bucle al segundo), es una de las diagonales de la matriz.

Elementos: (9, 0), (8, 1), (7, 2), ...

La suma de la fila y la columna para cada elemento de la diagonal es 9, por lo que esta manera alternativa es recorrer la fila hasta encontrar un elemento de la diagonal, y entonces seguir recorriendo, pero la columna correspondiente, a partir de ese elemento.

```
#define LADO 10

int main(void)
{
    // ...

    int matriz[LADO][LADO];
    int sumas[LADO];

    for (int suma = 0; suma < LADO; suma++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; suma + j < LADO - 1; j++) suma += matriz[suma][j];

        int i;
        for (i = suma; i < LADO; i++) suma += matriz[i][j];
    }

    // ...
}
```